# Writing a custom token validator class for WSO2 v1.9

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a requirement to write a custom token validator class for wso2 api management. I tried extending the DefaultOAuth2TokenValidator class, converted it into a jar and placed in /repository/components/extensions. Code snippet is mentioned below.

```
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.IdentityOAuth2Exception;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.validators.DefaultOAuth2TokenValidator;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.validators.OAuth2TokenValidationMessageContext;


public class CustomTokenValidator extends DefaultOAuth2TokenValidator{

    public boolean validateAccessToken(OAuth2TokenValidationMessageContext arg0)
            throws IdentityOAuth2Exception
          {
            System.out.println("CUSTOM VALIDATION INVOKED");
            return true;
          }

}
```

I added the following as the last sub-entry under  tag in /repository/conf/identity.xml

```
<TokenValidators>
            <TokenValidator type="bearer" class="com.example.custom.token.generator.CustomTokenValidator"/>
        </TokenValidators>
```

I put all the missing jars (class not found exception while restarting sevrer) in the same location till it threw the error mentioned below. I am at a loss. Kindly advise.

```
[2015-09-24 12:52:36,287]  INFO - AgentDS Successfully deployed Agent Client
[2015-09-24 12:52:59,246] ERROR - RegistryConfigurationProcessor Could not initialize custom handlers. Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.handlers.APIConfigMediaTypeHandl
e cast to org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.Handler
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.handlers.APIConfigMediaTypeHandler cannot be cast to org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.Handler
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryConfigurationProcessor$HandlerDefinitionObject.invoke(RegistryConfigurationProcessor.java:967)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryConfigurationProcessor.buildHandler(RegistryConfigurationProcessor.java:612)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryConfigurationProcessor.initializeHandlers(RegistryConfigurationProcessor.java:564)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryConfigurationProcessor.populateRegistryConfig(RegistryConfigurationProcessor.java:388)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryContext.<init>(RegistryContext.java:468)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryContext.<init>(RegistryContext.java:449)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryContext.getBaseInstance(RegistryContext.java:328)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.getEmbeddedRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:627)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.buildRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:563)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.activate(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:117)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:69)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
[2015-09-24 12:52:59,329] ERROR - RegistryContext Unable to get instance of the registry context
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Could not initialize custom handlers. Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.handlers.APIConfigMediaTypeHandler ca
t to org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.Handler
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryConfigurationProcessor.initializeHandlers(RegistryConfigurationProcessor.java:570)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryConfigurationProcessor.populateRegistryConfig(RegistryConfigurationProcessor.java:388)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryContext.<init>(RegistryContext.java:468)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryContext.<init>(RegistryContext.java:449)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryContext.getBaseInstance(RegistryContext.java:328)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.getEmbeddedRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:627)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.buildRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:563)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.activate(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:117)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:69)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.handlers.APIConfigMediaTypeHandler cannot be cast to org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.Handler
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryConfigurationProcessor$HandlerDefinitionObject.invoke(RegistryConfigurationProcessor.java:967)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryConfigurationProcessor.buildHandler(RegistryConfigurationProcessor.java:612)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryConfigurationProcessor.initializeHandlers(RegistryConfigurationProcessor.java:564)
        ... 44 more
[2015-09-24 12:52:59,416] ERROR - RegistryCoreServiceComponent Failed to activate Registry Core bundle
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.getEmbeddedRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:629)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.buildRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:563)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.activate(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:117)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:69)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
[2015-09-24 12:52:59,507]  INFO - UserStoreMgtDSComponent Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
[2015-09-24 12:53:08,068]  INFO - TaglibUriRule TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the JAR file into `<WSO2_AM>/repository/components/lib` directory.

Comment: Hi @AbimaranKugathasan - We tried the way you have specified and copied jars to lib folder. Still the result remains the same. Are we doing something wrong or we are using inappropriate version? Here are the list of jars we have copied to the component lib: amber_0.22.1358727.wso2v5.jar
CustomTokenValidator.jar
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_1.2.4.jar
org.wso2.carbon.identity.base_4.2.6.jar
org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth_4.2.6.jar
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.2.0.jar

Comment: You need to copy your validator jar `CustomTokenValidator.jar ` only to the lib directory. Others are already shipped with APIM. FYI, API Manager 1.9.1 released with minor bug fixes.

Comment: Hi @AbimaranKugathasan - that got deployed successfully and my classes are getting invoked, but still I am not able to bypass the token validation. What ever be the token I am returning boolean true so I believe even in case of invalid token my api call should go through, but this is not happening. Got following message : ERROR - AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl Invalid OAuth Token : Invalid input. Access token validation failed

Comment: One more thing - We have just added <TokenValidators> tag in identity.xml and specified our custom class. Just curious whether we need to add/update/delete other entries in identity.xml. Please advise.